# Finding path maximum in 2D array

Tags: c

Halloween is round the corner and it's time for trick-or-treating. You reside at the top left corner of a n-by-n town map and heading to the halloween party located at the bottom right corner. While on your trip, you decide to visit a minimal number of houses to get treats. You have a map of town with information of the amount of treats (≥ 0) available at each location. As an example, the town map for n=3 is shown below.

6 8 2

4 5 1

3 9 10

To get the maximum treats, you will start from home (6), then head east to (8), then south to (5), then south to (9), then east to (10) and end up at the party.

So the number of treats is 6+8+5+9+10=38.

Notice that to visit a minimal number of houses, it necessitates that you either travel east or south from one house to the next until you arrive at the party. To obtain the maximum treats, track the current maximum as you visit each home.

6, 14, 2+14=16

10, 5+max(10,14)=19

3+10=13

So the program needs to be choosing the maximum value to add let's say for 10 and 14, i will choose to add 14. But I have trouble with this using for loops. Anyone can help?

---

```html
1 #include <stdio.h>
  2
  3 #define SIZE 10
  4
  5 int pathmax(int map[][SIZE], int n);
  6 void read(int map[][SIZE], int n);
  7 int max(int x, int y);
  8
  9 int main(void)
 10 {
 11    int map[SIZE][SIZE], n;
 12
 13    printf("Enter n: ");
 14    scanf("%d", &n);
 15
 16    read(map,n);
 17
 18    printf("Maximum: %d\n", pathmax(map,n));
 19
 20    return 0;
 21 }
 22
 23 int max(int x, int y)
 24 {
 25    if (x > y)
 26       return x;
 27    else
 28       return y;
 29 }
 30
 31 int pathmax(int map[][SIZE], int n)
 32 {
 33    int k, i, j;
 34
 35    for (k = 1; k < 2*n-1; k++)
 36       for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 37          for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                  if(i+j==k)
                    {
                     if (i==0)
                         map[i][j] += map[i][j-1];
                     else if (j == 0)
                         map[i][j] += map[i-1][j];
                     else
                         map[i][j] += max(map[i-1][j], map[i][j-1];
                               }
                               
                               }
```

Comment: Looks like somebody wont be getting a lot of candy this year.

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, try your professor.

Comment: For loops have nothing to do with your inability to choose the maximum of two numbers. That can be achieved by a conditional (either `if` or the `?:` operator) and one of `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution, will teacher believe you wrote it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXTREAT    10
#define GRID        3

int map [GRID][GRID];
int maxtreats;

void explore(int x, int y, int treats)
{
    treats += map [y][x];
    if (x == GRID-1 && y == GRID-1) {   // reached bottom right?
        if (treats > maxtreats)         // check result
            maxtreats = treats;         // finish recursion
    } else {                            // recurse
        if (x+1 < GRID)
            explore (x+1, y, treats);   // go east
        if (y+1 < GRID)
            explore (x, y+1, treats);   // go south
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    srand ((unsigned int)time(NULL));  // seed random num gen
    for (x=0; x<GRID; x++) {           // set up random map
        for (y=0; y<GRID; y++) {
            map[y][x] = 1 + rand() % MAXTREAT;
            printf ("%4d", map[y][x]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    explore (0, 0, 0);
    printf ("Max treats %d\n", maxtreats);
    return 0;
}
```